# Trying to use Embedded Documents Fields in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm following freecodecamp's video on MongoDB using mongoengine (as db). I'm trying to use the embedded document list field to add information to my main document. Also using a Streamlit webapp as my input source

My class's are:

```py
class Contest(db.Document):
    date_created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
    format = db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Format)

class Format(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    contest_id = db.ObjectIdField()
    name = db.StringField()
```

Then I've tried a few different ways to to add the format to a specific contest instance.

Try #1

```py
def set_format(active_contest):
    format : Format = None
    name = st.text_input('Name of Format:')
    submit = st.button('Set Format Name')
    if submit == True:
        format.contest_id = active_contest.id
        format.name = name
        active_contest.save()
```

setting Format to None is the way the freecodecamp video shows... but i get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contest_id'.

So I tried switching it to: `format = Format()`... this way it doesn't give me an error, but also doesn't update the Contest document to include the format information.

I also tried switching `active_contest.save()` to `format.save()` but then i get a: AttributeError: 'Format' object has no attribute 'save'

I've also tried the update function instead of save... but i get similar errors every-which way.

New to mongoDB and programming in general. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to store Format as embedded document, the contest_id is not necessary in Format class. With this approach you will end with something like this in your MongoDB collection:

```
{
  "date_created":ISODate(...),
  "name": "...",
  "format": {
    "name": "..."
  }
}
```

Another approach could be something like:

```
class Contest(db.Document):
    date_created = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.today)
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
    format = db.ReferenceField('Format') # <- Replaced by ReferenceField

class Format(db.Document): # <- EmbeddedDocument replaced by Document
    name = db.StringField()
```

In that case each instance of "Format" will be stored in a separate collection. So you will end with something like this in MongoDB:

Collection Contest:

```
{
  "date_created":ISODate(...),
  "name": "...",
  "format": :ObjectId("...") // <-- here's the relation field
}
```

Collection Format:

```
{
    "_id":"...",
    "name":"..",
}
```

Both approaches shares the same code:

```
def set_format(active_contest): # <-- here's the instance of 'Contest'
    format : Format = Format() # <-- create a new Format instance
    name = st.text_input('Name of Format:')
    submit = st.button('Set Format Name')
    if submit == True:
        format.name = name
        active_contest.format = format # <-- assigns the format to contest
        active_contest.save() <- stores both because you are saving the 'parent' object
```